# Filtering a Date (string) converted to date SQL Query in a MVC application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

so at the moment, I'm refurbishing an application at a company, in which I was asked to create a form where I can submit a date and then on another screen (razor page) I ask the bd for info between two dates.

So this is part of the code that should "print" the table

```
public partial class Espolio : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gvbindespolios();
                EspoliosSearch();
                //FilterPageLoader();
            }
        }

        


        //Method of the searchboxes for the menu Espolio
        protected void EspoliosSearch()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Carrier_LASOConnection"].ConnectionString;

            string querycentroc = "select distinct isnull(vd.costcentercode,'') [CC] from tms.vehicledetails vd inner join tms.vehicles v on v.licenceplate=vd.LicensePlateNumber where v.isdeleted=0 order by isnull(vd.costcentercode,'') ASC";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                // Lists the costcented cordes ( filters by cost center ) 
                using (SqlCommand cmdcentroc = new SqlCommand(querycentroc))
                {
                    SqlDataReader srcentroc;

                    cmdcentroc.Connection = con;
                    cmdcentroc.Connection.Open();

                    srcentroc = cmdcentroc.ExecuteReader();

                    while (srcentroc.Read())
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem listcentroc = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();

                        listcentroc.Value = srcentroc["cc"].ToString();
                        listcentroc.Value = srcentroc["cc"].ToString();

                        Ddepartamento.Items.Add(listcentroc);
                    }

                    Ddepartamento.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
                    srcentroc.Close();
                    cmdcentroc.Connection.Close();
                }
            } 
        }

        
        // Method which "fills" the table ( MAIN )
        protected void gvbindespolios()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Carrier_LASOConnection"].ConnectionString;
            string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("LASODOM\\", "");

            String Nome = strName;

            string queryespolio = @"Select e.Id, e.Matricula[Matrícula], v.Brand[Marca], e.DataEspolio[Data do Espólio], d.name[Nome Motorista], e.IDMotorista[ID Motorista], vd.Mobile[Móvel], CostCenterCode[Centro de Custo]
                                    From Laso.Espolios e
                                inner Join Tms.Vehicles v on v.LicencePlate = e.Matricula
                                inner Join Tms.Drivers d on d.Id= e.IDMotorista
                                inner Join Tms.VehicleDetails vd on vd.LicensePlateNumber = v.LicencePlate
                                    where v.isdeleted=0 and
                                replace(vd.LicensePlateNumber,' ','') like '%" + TMatricula.Text.Replace(" ", "") +
                                "%' and replace(vd.mobile,' ','') like '%" + Tmovel.Text.Trim() +
                                "%' and e.DataEspolio like '%" + Tdatainicio.Text +
                                "%' and d.name like '%" + Tmotoristanome.Text.ToString() +
                                "%' and vd.costcentercode like '%" + Ddepartamento.SelectedValue.ToString().TrimEnd().TrimStart() +
                                "%' and v.Brand like '%" + Tmarca.Text.ToString().TrimEnd().TrimStart() +
                                "%' and d.Id like '%" + Tmotorista.Text.ToString() + "%'" +
                                " and (@datainicio != '' AND @datafim != '' AND dataespolio between TRY_CONVERT(date, @datainicio, 23) AND TRY_CONVERT(date, @datafim, 23)) OR " +
                                "(@datainicio != '' AND @datafim = '' AND dataespolio between TRY_CONVERT(date, @datainicio, 23) and getdate()) OR " +
                                "(@datainicio = '' AND @datafim = '')" + "order by e.Id Desc";

            SqlParameter pardatinc = new SqlParameter("@datainicio", Tdatainicio.Text);
            SqlParameter pardatfim = new SqlParameter("@datafim", Tdatafim.Text);

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdespolio = new SqlCommand(queryespolio))
                {
                    cmdespolio.Parameters.Add(pardatinc);
                    cmdespolio.Parameters.Add(pardatfim);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sdaespolio = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmdespolio.Connection = con;
                        cmdespolio.Connection.Open();
                        sdaespolio.SelectCommand = cmdespolio;
                        using (DataTable dtespolio = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sdaespolio.Fill(dtespolio);

                            GvEspolios.DataSource = dtespolio;
                            GvEspolios.DataBind();
                            ViewState["dirStateespolio"] = dtespolio;
                            ViewState["sortdrespolio"] = "Desc";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Tpesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvbindespolios();
        }

        protected void Tclear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TMatricula.Text = "";
            Tmotorista.Text = "";
            Tmotoristanome.Text = "";
            Ddepartamento.ClearSelection();
            Tmovel.Text = "";
            Tmarca.Text = "";
            Tdatainicio.Text = "";
            Tdatafim.Text = "";
        }
```

**FRONT END**
so over here it's the frontend side:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div style="height:950px; width:1500px; background:#ffffff;" class="auto-style8">

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" 
                   BackColor="#005172" ForeColor="White" 
                   Font-Size="Large" Font-Names="Helvetica">
                <label class="LabelTitulo">Espólios</label> 
            </asp:Panel>
         <br />
            <!-- Tabela com campos de search Espolios-->
            <table>
               <tr dir="auto">
                <td style="color: #a3a8b8; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; font-weight: bold">
                    <label class="Label">Matrícula</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="TMatricula" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Search" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                   <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Marca</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tmarca" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Search"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Móvel</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tmovel" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Search"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Desde</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tdatainicio" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Até</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tdatafim" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Motorista</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tmotoristanome" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Search"></asp:TextBox> 
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                    <label class="Label">ID Motorista</label><br /><asp:TextBox ID="Tmotorista" ccsClass="Textbox" TextMode="Search" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td dir="auto" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #a3a8b8; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">
                     <label class="Label">Centro Custo</label><br /><asp:DropDownList ID="Ddepartamento" runat="server" cssClass="TextBox" TextMode="Search"></asp:DropDownList> 
                </td>
                 
               </tr>
            </table>
             <!-- FIM Tabela com campos de search Espolios-->
            <asp:Button ID="Tpesquisar"
                        runat="server"
                        cssClass="buttonwhite"
                        OnClick="Tpesquisar_Click"
                            Text="Pesquisar"
                            />
            <asp:Button ID="Tclear"
                        runat="server"
                        cssClass="buttonwhite"
                        text="Limpar filtro"
                        OnClick="Tclear_Click"   
                            />
                        <!--OnClick="Tclear_Click"-->

            <asp:Button ID="Tinserirespolio" 
                        runat="server"
                        cssClass="button"
                        OnClick="Tinserirespolio_Click"
                            Text="Novo Espólio"
                             />
            
            <asp:Button ID="Texportarespolio" 
                        runat="server"
                        cssClass="button"
                        OnClick="Texportarespolio_Click"
                            Text="Exportar Tabela"/>
           
            <asp:Button ID="Texportarhistoricoesp" 
                        runat="server"
                        cssClass="button"
                        OnClick="Texportarhistoricoesp_Click"
                            Text="Exportar Histórico"/>
         <asp:GridView ID="GvEspolios"
                       style="
                            margin-left:10px;
                            margin-top:18px;
                            width:99%" 
                       runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" CellPadding="15"
                       ForeColor="#7C839B" Font-Names="Helvetica" Font-Size="Smaller"
                       GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="none"
                       BackColor="White" 
                       ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CellSpacing="2"
                       OnPageIndexChanging="GvEspolios_PageIndexChanging"
                      >
                       
             <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" 
                                             runat="server" 
                                             CausesValidation="false" 
                                             CommandName="" 
                                             ImageUrl="~/content/Imagens/edit.png" 
                                             Text="Detalhes" 
                                             Height="25px" Width="25px" 
                                             OnClick="Detalhesespolios_Click"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle Font-Names="Oswald" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" 
                             Font-Bold="False"
                             Font-Names="Helvetica"
                             ForeColor="#A3A8B8"
                             Font-Size="12px"/>
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F9F9F9" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#7c839b" 
                            BackColor="White" 
                            Font-Names="Helvetica" 
                            Font-Size="Small" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

So for example I have a register on the db that has a date 2021-05-26
and when I try to search for a value that is before that date, it shouldn't appear. It doesn't, so it's correct. But when I choose a date stamp that contains that date (26) it doesn't appear also.

I was able to make it right but I can't understand why now I can't filter it.

If I do the same query on the db I can actually see the value.

```
DECLARE @datainicio NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @datafim NVARCHAR(10)

SET @datainicio = '2021-05-20'
SET @datafim = '2021-05-27'

SELECT e.Id,
       e.Matricula   [Matrícula],
       v.Brand       [Marca],
       e.DataEspolio [Data do Espólio],
       d.NAME        [Nome Motorista],
       e.IDMotorista [ID Motorista],
       vd.Mobile     [Móvel],
       CostCenterCode[Centro de Custo]
FROM   laso.Espolios e
       INNER JOIN tms.Vehicles v
               ON v.LicencePlate = e.Matricula
       INNER JOIN tms.Drivers d
               ON d.Id = e.IDMotorista
       INNER JOIN tms.VehicleDetails vd
               ON vd.LicensePlateNumber = v.LicencePlate
WHERE  v.isdeleted = 0
       AND Replace(vd.LicensePlateNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '%%'
       AND Replace(vd.mobile, ' ', '') LIKE '%%'
       AND e.DataEspolio LIKE '%%'
       AND d.NAME LIKE '%%'
       AND vd.costcentercode LIKE '%%'
       AND v.Brand LIKE '%%'
       AND d.Id LIKE '%%'
       AND ( @datainicio != ''
             AND @datafim != ''
             AND dataespolio BETWEEN Try_convert(date, @datainicio, 23) AND
                                     Try_convert(date, @datafim, 23) )
        OR ( @datainicio != ''
             AND @datafim = ''
             AND dataespolio BETWEEN Try_convert(date, @datainicio, 23) AND
                                     Getdate() )
        OR ( @datainicio = ''
             AND @datafim = '' )
ORDER  BY e.Id DESC
```

Comment: **Don't** convert the date to a string. Don't concatenate strings to create SQL queries, use parameterized queries. Concatenating strings exposes you to SQL injection attacks (imagine what would happen with `'; drop table users ;--` as input` *and* conversion errors like the one you encountered

Comment: If you use parameterized queries and strongly typed values like `DateTime` you'll be able to eliminate all those convertion attempts and simplify the code a *lot*. Eg `dataespolio between @datainicio and @datafim`

Comment: I see there are other SQL injection problems as well. `replace(vd.LicensePlateNumber,' ','') like '%" + TMatricula.Text.Replace(" ", "") ` became `replace(vd.LicensePlateNumber,' ','') like '%%'`. This will scan. the entire table but filter nothing. This query has significant security and performance problems

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for the tips. I'm a trainee, so at the moment I'm trying to learn the best way to do things, most of the decisions I make come from what I find on the internet. I will change those other issues.

Comment: `come from what I find on the internet` that's a *very* bad idea. You need to understand what's going on to be able to tell if what you read is good or bad. By definition, half of it will be below average. If you want to learn how to work with Razor Pages, read the Microsoft [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and reputable courses (ie not Udemy). Reputable authors won't publish nonsense otherwise they'll go out of business. Google Search never forgets a mistake

Answer (score 0):

`SqlParameter` not need change date format you can set `DataType` for fixed your issue.

[SqlParameter property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#example)

If not fxied your issue you can change DateText To DateTime

```
var yourDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Tdatainicio.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I hope fixed your problem

Comment: Hi Zanyar, I've tried multiple things and at the moment none of the options is working.. When I add the date filter to the query, it only searches the date and if I use any of the other values, it keeps loading the same only value that is created.. But thank you anyway.